# How to make a following button design in the flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

thanks for opening the question, I am learning the flutter and I am learning about the button, I want to make the following design in the flutter

[image]

but am not able to find any widget which can be used, there is something the icon in the elevated button which I have used but I am not able to achieve the design.

using the elevatedButton.icon

[image]

```
  return SizedBox(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: 48,
    child: ElevatedButton.icon(
      icon:Icon(
        prefixIcon, // passing from the main widget 
      ),
      onPressed: () => {},
      label: Text(text),
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: backgroundColor
      ),
    ),
  );
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to below answer hope its helpful to you

```
    Container(
        width: 250,
        height: 50,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              Icon(Icons.login), //use your google image here
              Text('Sign in with Google '),
              Opacity(
                opacity: 0,
                child: Icon(Icons.login),
              )
            ],
          ),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Your Button look like this-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to achieve your desired widget:

```dart
Container(
    width: 256,
    height: 48,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: ElevatedButton(
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: const <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.login), // your google image
          Expanded(child: Center(child: Text('Sign in with Google'))),
        ],
      ),
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.red),
      onPressed: () {},
    ),
  );
```

[image]