# Flutter How to align row widget children to left and center

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am trying to create social login buttons like below image. I want to align textbutton icon and name to left. also center the row they are in so that the icon and text align vertically when using multiple text buttons.

expected result:

[image]

My Result:

[image]

My Code for button:

```
TextButton(
        onPressed: onTap,
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                width: 30,
                child: Image.asset(
                  icon,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                buttonName,
                style: kBodyText2,
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(SizeConfig.blockSizeH! * 3),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: Try my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68788609/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that by using the `Expanded` widget: Like so:

```
Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextButton(
    onPressed: (){},
    child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Container(),),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                width: 30,
                child: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'test text test',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
    ),
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
    ),
  ),
      ),
      const SizedBox(height: 30),
      Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: TextButton(
    onPressed: (){},
    child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Expanded(flex: 1, child: Container(),),
          Expanded(
            flex: 2,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20),
                width: 30,
                child: Icon(Icons.access_alarm),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 5,
            child: Align(
              alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
              child: Text(
                'test text test test',
                textAlign: TextAlign.left,
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
    ),
    style: TextButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        ),
    ),
  ),
      ),
```

Comment: you misunderstood my question i want to align text and icon to left and center both so they align vertically when i use multiple buttons.

Comment: Aah, I understand now. Updated my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can exploit the fact the these icons are the same size, to easily align them. Each of your `TextButton` already holds a `Row`, but instead of fancy layout stuff, you can just insert padding to the `Icon` by adding blank spaces using `SizedBox`, like so:

```
TextButton(
  child: Row(
    children: [
      const SizedBox(width: 16), // padding in the beginning
      Icon(Icons.download), // the icon, or image, or whatever
      const SizedBox(width: 16), // padding in-between
      Text('Button ' * i), // the text
    ],
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
)
```

Result:

[image: demo picture]

Code used to produce the above demo:

```
Column(
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: [
    for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
      TextButton(
        child: Row(
          children: [
            const SizedBox(width: 16),
            Icon(Icons.download),
            const SizedBox(width: 16),
            Text('Button ' * i),
          ],
        ),
        onPressed: () {},
        style: TextButton.styleFrom(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
          ),
        ),
      ),
  ],
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [ListTile()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ListTile-class.html)
instead.
Set title: "Continue with Google".
And leading: you can set the logo.
The positions will always stay the same no matter how long your title will be, you also have extra options like subtitles and trailing actions.
To make it act like a button use
onTap: (){}