# Centered Text inside a button with an icon in Flutter

Tags: flutter, mobile, flutter-layout

I'm having issues where I want to make a button (any kind to achieve this) that has an icon that is always in the same position at the start of the button, and that the text of the button is always centered compared to the text below it and always centered in the button itself, even if the text is dynamic. This is what I want to achieve:
[image]

The button text is centered according to the text below(that stays the same) and it is centered with the above button, but if the button text changes dynamically, then I have these issues:

[image]

Or like this one:

[image]

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

I tried with the `Expanded` widget and adding the flex properties but failed. I tried some other stuff too but failed also... Here is the button code:

```
TextButton(
                              style: ButtonStyle(
                                  backgroundColor:
                                      MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue)),
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: Row(
                                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 1,
                                    child: Icon(
                                      Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_sharp,
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  Expanded(
                                    flex: 4,
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        "SOME TEXT",
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Refer my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68788609/13997210) hope its helpful to you

Comment: Thanks mate once again, this is exactly what I needed, but if you don't mind I will accept the answer below as he took the time to write the whole solution with two variations, even though it's a similar solution. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options to do that. I'm going to assume the size of the text could change so you want a flexible solution.

The first option is the most obvious of the two, but will break if the text is too long. The trick is to add an empty sizedBox at the end of the button, so the text can be centered in an expanded widget.

```
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Icon(
        Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_sharp,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 24,
      ),
      Expanded(
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            "SOME TEXT",
            style: TextStyle(
              color:Colors.white,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      SizedBox(
        width: 24, // width of the icon
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

The other option is using a stack widget. This way, if the text is too long it will overlap with the icon but it's less probable that it will overflow the button.

```
TextButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue),
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Positioned(
        left: 0,
        child: Icon(
          Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_sharp,
          color: Colors.white,
          size: 24,
        ),
      ),
      Center(
        child: Text(
          "SOME TEXT",
          style: TextStyle(
            color:Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mate, this is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 0):

Let's discuss about you code :
using row with a mainaxisalignment from start make the element start from the available area. then i suggest to use the `SizedBox` to make some of spacing between the elements as you want and play with the width of it.

```
TextButton(
                          style: ButtonStyle(
                              backgroundColor:
                                  MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue)),
                          onPressed: () {},
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, // here the issue
                            children: [
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 1,
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_sharp,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                              ),
                             SizedBox(width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.08, // change this value as you want 0.08 or 0.1 ...etc
      ),
                              Expanded(
                                flex: 4,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Text(
                                    "SOME TEXT",
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
```

for more read this [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/widgets)

Comment: When using flexible widgets (like Expanded, Spacer...), the available space of the row will be completely filled on the main axis, so the mainAxisAlignment property won't do anything in this case.

Comment: What @lule said, this was not the issue, the issue I had is to add 3 element in a row, which 2 are the same width (first and third child of the row) and wrap the middle child of the row, the `Text` widget, in an expanded so the dynamic change of the text (a longer text) fit inside the button itself.